# WiFi access points blocking VPN

Tags: wifi, firewalls, vpn

I've been travelling for awhile and used a lot of Wifi access point lately. Several times my attempts to connect with VPN has been blocked (especially when using a "famous" one), and I've also noticed that some places even block TLS negotiations.

1. How are they doing this?
2. How can I circumvent it?

Comment: 2. is likely to be off-topic - it would be breaking a security system, without an educational understanding as the purpose.

Comment: Actually, if they are disallowing TLS I would say they are breaking MY security system.

Comment: Not really - you're using their network, so it's their rules. You aren't obliged to use it - you could get your own mobile internet connection, for example.